# Angular 5 Material Update mat-select when List of mat-options Change

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my Angular 5 application, I have an input box that, when enter is pressed, calls an API that returns an array.  This array is then used in an mat-select to populate the mat-options.  The first item is automatically selected, but the display value never updates.

In other words, when a mat-select is populated with dynamic data, an assignment to its ngModel is not reflected in its display value.

`component.html`:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Order ID" [(ngModel)]="orderID (keydown)="handleKeyDown($event)">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Product ID"  (change)="showProductDetails(productID)" [(ngModel)]="productID" >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.id"> {{ product.name }} </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

`component.ts`:

```ts
orderID = '';
products = [];

handleKeyDown(event: any) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) { this.getProductIDs(); }
}

getProductIDs(){

    ... /~ Call API and populate "products"  ~~/

    // Update the mat-select's ngModel - value is updated but display is not
    productID = products[0].id;
}

showProductDetails(productID){ /~~ Do some stuff }
```

Answer (score 4):

An example from Angular Material docs:

[image]

So you should use `[(value)]` instead of regular `[(ngModel)]`, like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Product ID"  (change)="showProductDetails(productID)" [(value)]="productID" >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.id"> {{ product.name }} </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Both value and ngModel perform the same in this case. The issue was actually related to a browser extension that was stripping off the ID because it thought it was a phone number. Either way, it is solved.